# Google geolocation using cell tower info- Curl 400 Bad request PHP

Tags: php, curl, geolocation, google-api, google-geolocation

I'm trying to get latitude and longitude from cell tower info using [Google's geolocation api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/#overview).
It requires a valid JSON with information like MCC, MNC, cellId, lac etc.., My PHP post request looks like this.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$mcc = $_POST["mcc"];
$mnc = $_POST["mnc"];
$cellId = $_POST["cellId"];
$lac = $_POST["lac"];

$post_array = array(
                "cellId" => (int) $cellId,
                "locationAreaCode" => (int) $lac,
                "mobileCountryCode" => (int) $mcc,
                "mobileNetworkCode" => (int) $mnc,
            );

$post_data = json_encode(array('cellTowers' => array($post_array)));

echo $post_data;


$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=".$api_key; // not including api key here but its there in my code

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post_data
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo "Result: ".$result;

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

However I get an error saying bad request in the response. The error is shown below.

```
Result: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "geolocation",
    "reason": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

I thought my JSON was not in the correct format but it was working with the following command line execution, so that can't be the issue.

```
$ curl -d @your_filename.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=API_KEY"
```

The above command in terminal gives lattitude and longitude properly with the same JSON in a file. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $DadosLBS['homeMobileCountryCode'] = $data['MCC'];
    $DadosLBS['homeMobileNetworkCode'] = $data['MNC'];
    $DadosLBS['radioType'] = 'gsm';
    $DadosLBS['carrier'] = $data['MNCOperator'];
    $DadosLBS['cellTowers'] = [
        [
            'mobileCountryCode' => $data['MCC'],
            'mobileNetworkCode' => $data['MNC'],
            'age' => $data['Age'],
            'timingAdvance' => $data['TA'],
            'locationAreaCode' => $data['LAC'],
            'cellId' => $data['CELL_ID'],
            'signalStrength' => $data['SIGNAL'],
        ],
    ];


        //Ver detalhes da API no https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro?hl=pt-br

    $service_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate";

    //Chave de acesso
    $Curl_Data = array(
        'key' => <YOUR KEY HERE>
    );

    $CurlQueryString = http_build_query($Curl_Data);

    //Preparando o método a ser enviado os dados
    $Metodo = array(
        CURLOPT_URL         => $service_url.'?'.$CurlQueryString // Define URL to be called
    );

    //Criando s string de dados
    $DadosPost = json_encode($DadosLBS);

    //Preparando as opções padrões do CUrl
    $Curl_Adicional_Options = array(
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST       => "POST"
        ,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS         => $DadosPost
        ,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER     => true              // return web page
        ,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT     => 15               // time-out on connect
        ,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT            => 15               // time-out on response
        ,CURLOPT_FAILONERROR        => true             //
        ,CURLOPT_HEADER             => false            // don't return headers
        ,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER         => array(
                                                'Content-Type: application/json',
                                                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($DadosPost)
                                       ) // Dados para o cabeçalho do post
        ,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION     => true             // follow redirects
        ,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS          => 10               // stop after 10 redirects
        ,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER     => false
        ,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST     => false
    );

    $Curl_Options = array_replace_recursive($Metodo,$Curl_Adicional_Options);

    $cURLConn = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($cURLConn, $Curl_Options);

    $vDados['Curl']['Output']       = curl_exec($cURLConn);
    $vDados['Curl']['Error']        = curl_error($cURLConn);
    $vDados['Curl']['ErrorNum']     = curl_errno($cURLConn);
    $vDados['Curl']['ErrorMsg']     = curl_strerror($vDados['Curl']['ErrorNum']);
    $vDados['Curl']['Info']         = curl_getinfo($cURLConn);

    curl_close($cURLConn);

    if ($vDados['Curl']['ErrorNum'] != 0) {
        $Dados['loc'] = array(
            'status' => 'ERROR',
            'error' => array(
                'error_cod' => $vDados['Curl']['ErrorNum'],
                'error_msg' => $vDados['Curl']['ErrorMsg']
            )
        );
        return $Dados['loc'];
    }

    //Tratando as respostas
    $vDados['Curl']['Dados'] = json_decode($vDados['Curl']['Output']) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

    print_r($vDados['Curl']['Dados']);
```

Don't forget to create our key on google console.